# Can't reach pressure

Tags: canning, broth

I couldn't get my canner above 5 lbs. After taking the lid and trying again increasing the heat and adjusting the gasket for 3 hours I needed to give up the stove for dinner.  After opening up and taking out the jars one was open but the others seem sealed.  It wasn't processed as needed (25 minutes at 10psi) what do I do now? Can they be reprocessed in fresh water?